# Thread run with a while loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a simple multi-threaded program as follows:

I have T1,T2,T3...Tn threads, which all run in parallel.
Each thread has a queue of objects, which I want to add/remove items from.
In every single addition, I'd like to print it to the screen.

```
public void run() {
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Object obj = queue.poll();
            System.out.println(obj.toString());
    }
}
```

And for addition, I simply use:

```
void addObj(Object obj) {
    this.queue.add(obj);
}
```

In the same class of the thread.

I am using `addObj` across the program, in different times.

**The problem** when I add objects to the queue, it doesn't seem that `run` even cares.
In some cases it did print the new object, but in many cases it did not, and it still considered the queue as empty.

How can I make sure that the thread is aware of this item being added?
Should I use any callback?
What is the right approach for such tasks?

- I also noticed that when I use `Thred.sleep()` it helps, but it looks pretty ugly, I guess.

**UPDATE**: each thread **should** have it's own thread. I am creating the threads in a separte "thread-manger" which starts them one by one.
Each thread has it's own private queue, which should be filled on the fly.
Items can be add/removed to the queues in any given time, before and after the threads started.

Comment: What *exactly* is `queue`? Is it some kind of concurrent, waitable queue?

Comment: what about BlockingQueue ?

Comment: Because Thread.sleep() helps, you have most likely created a race condition. Could you post how your threads are created? And how you make sure the queue is filled before the thread is executed?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz queue is just a simple queue, should'nt it bee?

Comment: @JanGroothuijse I can't make sure the queue is filled before execution. The whole idea of this program is that objects can be sent in any time, as well as on the fly...

Comment: @superuser123 No, it can't be. If you are expecting a thread to be able to *wait* for the queue to fill, the queue has to be waitable. And if you're expecting the queue to be used by threads concurrently, the queue has to be concurrent. If it's neither of those things, the code won't work.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I guess I did not explain myself properly, I'll update my question...

Comment: Ok as mentioned by the others , it is clear what you want to do , but your design wont operate as expected. As you pointed , you have a custom Thread Manager , so this should be responsible to forward the tasks to the appropriate pool , not to a thread which you kept it awake for an infinite time(thats why we have thread pools). More likely you need an Event Bus approach , or even Consumer Producer pattern. In order to be full scalable and concurrent , you should follow something like the `Observable` which might not affect your code so much. But again making custom runnables,should be avoided

Comment: You said that "Each thread has it's own private queue". But in the same time you said "Items can be add/removed to the queues in any given time, before and after the threads started". There are some contradicts, aren't? If queue is filled before thread start then it's filled in other thread and it means that queue is not "own private queue" of this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `run()` method finishes immediately if the queue is empty. If you want threads to work event if queues are empty use something like this:

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Object obj = queue.poll();
            System.out.println(obj.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: probably its not working because he is keeping a clone inside the thread , so even if the actual `queue` reference got updated , the thread wont be notified at all , as it has a cloned reference.....

Comment: If cloned reference points on the same object than it's not a problem at all... but in the same time you are right, it's not clear if this queue is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Here a even prettier solution. Avoids polling ;)

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Object obj = queue.poll();
            System.out.println(obj.toString());
        }
        queue.wait();
    }
}
```

and here the code to add:

```
void addObj(Object obj) {
    this.queue.add(obj);
    this.queue.notify();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get this exception when doing that: `Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`

Comment: `wait()` and `notify()` works only inside `synchronized` block

Answer (score 0):

"each thread should have it's own thread" could you explain more? 
If you mean that the queue belongs to the thread, after doing an add you do a poll and you print what your message.